# Using loops to compute dice poker outcome

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a [*Dice poker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_dice) assignment. I have managed to generate an array that holds the frequencies of values rolled, but I can't write a loop to determine what the value of the hand is.

Hoping to get some advice on what combination of loops to use to determine what hand I'm holding. From there, I should be able to transpose this into a function, and write a function to compare this hand against others.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define handsz 5    //NO ACES IN THE POCKET WITH THIS GUY!
#define diesz 6     //All dice played will have 6 sides
#define ranks 7     //Seven ranks to hold

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   

int roll_die(void); 

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i;
    int player_hand[handsz] = { 0 };
    int donkeyvalue = 0;    
    int RandomNo;       

    for (i = 0; i < handsz; i++) {
        RandomNo = roll_die(donkeyvalue);  
        player_hand[i] = RandomNo;
    }

    int player_die_count[7] = { 0 }; 
    for (i = 0; i < handsz; i++) {
        player_die_count[player_hand[i]] = player_die_count[player_hand[i]] + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int roll_die(void) {
    return (1 + rand() % 6);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be an idea if you explained the rules...

Comment: OT: `... roll_die(donkeyvalue);` seems strange when you have `int roll_die(void);`

Comment: It is usually a good idea to separate variable declarations (place them on the first lines of a function) from the rest of the function body

Comment: it took me an embarrassingly large amount of time to get the random number function to work, but it does. I have functions that display and varify this (not included above).

Comment: Compile with a high level of warnings, and it will stop working :) `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: @chqrlie semantics didn't change. Offensive language?  Ok, anyway

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: sorry for implying that you changed the question in an offensive way, you actually restored the original text first edited out by *jonrsharpe*, probably because you had started the edit a while ago. However, changing the code to parenthesise macros, reorder declarations, and similar edits are not OK, you can provide such improvements in your answer, but the code in the question should not be amended this as it makes the discussion, comments and other answers inconsistent.

Comment: Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_dice

Comment: @Barry: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 1):

From the array `player_die_count`, using loops, you can determine:

- the number of *five of a kind*
- the number of *four of a kind*
- the number of *three of a kind*
- the number of pairs

And using a simple formula, you can determine if you have a straight:

```
has_straight = (player_die_count[1] == 1 && player_die_count[2] == 1 &&
                player_die_count[3] == 1 && player_die_count[4] == 1 && 
                player_die_count[5] == 1) ||
               (player_die_count[2] == 1 && player_die_count[3] == 1 &&
                player_die_count[4] == 1 && player_die_count[5] == 1 &&
                player_die_count[6] == 1);
```

Which can be simplified into:

```
has_straight = (player_die_count[2] * player_die_count[3] *
                player_die_count[4] * player_die_count[5]) == 1;
```

Then you can compute the payer's hand value from `0` to `7`:

- *Five of a kind*: 7 points
- *Four of a kind*: 6 points
- *Full house*: *three of a kind* plus a pair: 5 points
- *Straight*: 4 points
- *Three of a kind* : 3 points
- *Two pairs* : 2 points
- *One pair* : 1 point
- *Bust*: 0 point

You can refine the score by ranking the different combinations according to the values of the highest die. *five of a kind* of `6` beats *five of a kind* of `5`, etc.

Here is a complete program that outputs the score and the draw for a number of draws either using `rand()` or using a sequential distribution of all combinations:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define handsz 5
#define diesz  6     // All dice played will have 6 sides, numbered 1 to 6

static int roll_die(void) {
    return 1 + rand() % 6;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int iter = 1;
    int use_random = 1;

    if (argc > 1) {
        iter = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        if (iter < 0) {
            use_random = 0;
            iter = -iter;
        }
    }

    srand(clock());

    for (int n = 0; n < iter; n++) {
        int player_hand[handsz];

        if (use_random) {
            for (int i = 0; i < handsz; i++)
                player_hand[i] = roll_die();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0, mm = n; i < handsz; i++, mm /= 6)
                player_hand[i] = 1 + mm % 6;
        }

        int player_die_count[7] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < handsz; i++) {
            player_die_count[player_hand[i]] += 1;
        }

        int pairs, threes, fours, fives, score;
        pairs = threes = fours = fives = score = 0;
        for (int i = diesz; i > 0; i--) {
            switch (player_die_count[i]) {
            case 5:
                fives = i * 11111;
                break;
            case 4:
                fours = i * 1111;
                break;
            case 3:
                threes = i * 111;
                break;
            case 2:
                pairs = pairs * 100 + i * 11;
                break;
            case 1:
                score = score * 10 + i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (fives)
            score += 700000 + fives;
        else
        if (fours)
            score += 600000 + fours * 10;
        else
        if (threes && pairs)
            score += 500000 + threes * 100 + pairs;
        else
#ifndef NO_STRAIGHTS
        if (score == 54321 || score == 65432)
            score += 400000;
        else
#endif
        if (threes)
            score += 300000 + threes * 100;
        else
        if (pairs >= 100)
            score += 200000 + pairs * 10;
        else
        if (pairs)
            score += 100000 + pairs * 1000;

        printf("%d: %d %d %d %d %d\n",
               score, player_hand[0], player_hand[1],
               player_hand[2], player_hand[3], player_hand[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is very interesting to run the program with an argument of `7776` to check the actual distribution provided by the simplistic `roll_die` function. On my system, the pseudo-random distribution sometimes gives surprising results:

```
chqrlie$ ./pokerdice 7776 | sort -nr | head -10
755555: 5 5 5 5 5
744444: 4 4 4 4 4
744444: 4 4 4 4 4
722222: 2 2 2 2 2
711111: 1 1 1 1 1
711111: 1 1 1 1 1
711111: 1 1 1 1 1
711111: 1 1 1 1 1
666665: 6 6 6 5 6
666665: 6 6 5 6 6
```

Comment: that's very helpful. thankyou. Previously, my thought pattern was to assign a direct result instead of ranking with an arbitary value.

Comment: there are no "straights" in this game, only looking for 5, 4 of a kind, two pair etc. I will have  look at that though.

Comment: @Barry: the tricky part is the relative ranking of similar hands.

Comment: Why `*`/`+` to do the job of `&&`/`||`? It works, but it's weird. Maths for maths; logic for logic

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: just for fun: you have a straight if you have exactly one of each of these: `2` `3` `4` and `5`. I modified the answer with both approaches :)